# C++ Array passing to function with size

Tags: c++, arrays, max

I am writing **`C++`** code to get the maximum number from an array of integers using a function.

My code is as follows, but it's not working and I can't seem to fix it, I would like to know, if possible, what's wrong with it:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int maxfunc(int myArr, int size);
int main()
{
    int size;
    cout<<"Enterv the size of array: "<<size;
    int *arr=new int [size];
    for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        cout<<"Value No. "<<i+1<<" : ";
        cin>>arr[i];
    }
    int max = maxfunc(arr,size);
    cout<<"max = "<<max;

}
int maxfunc(int myArr, int size)
{
    int largest=myArr[0];
    for(int i=1; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(largest<myArr[i])
        {
            largest=myArr[i];
        }
    }
    return largest;
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the code is wrong? Did you run it expecting some certain output, but you got a different output? If so, can you say that and give those two outputs? Or do you get a compile time/run time error? If so, can you include the error?

Comment: @Die Hard You did not enter the size of the array.

Comment: btw what is wrong with the code is that you should use `std::max_element` instead of reinventing a wheel, but I have the feeling that is not what you are after ;)

Comment: I am getting this error at compile time invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' [-fpermissive].

Comment: compile your code with option to treat warnings as errors.

Comment: Voting to close as a typo.  `int maxfunc(int myArr, int size)` needs to be `int maxfunc(int* myArr, int size)` or `int maxfunc(int myArr[], int size)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
int maxfunc(int myArr, int size)
```

The argument `int myArr` is an integer but you are using it as an array of integers.
I would use a pointer to the original array:

```
int maxfunc(int *myArr, int size)
```

Another problem that stands out is that you are using `size` variable uninitalized, my gess is that you are missing a `cin >> size;`:

```
cout<<"Enterv the size of array: ";
cin >> size;
```

Finally, and this is opinion based, this is the kind of program you would use in C, for C++ there are better tools for storing a manipulating data. For this case I would recommend [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) or if the array is ment to have fixed size, [`std::array`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array).

Answer (score 0):

You did not entered the size of the array

```
int size;
cout<<"Enterv the size of array: "<<size;
int *arr=new int [size];
```

So the program has undefined behavior.

Also the function implementation is wrong because in general the user can pass the second argument equal to or less than 0.

The function should be declared like

```
size_t maxfunc( const int myArr[], size_t size);
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

and it should return the index of the maximum element.

The function can be implemented like

```
size_t maxfunc( const int myArr[], size_t size )
{
    size_t largest = 0;

    for ( size_t i = 1; i < size; i++ )
    {
        if ( myArr[largest] < myArr[i] )
        {
            largest = i;
        }
    }

    return largest;
}
```

And in main you can write

```
size_t max = maxfunc( arr, size );
cout << "max = " << arr[max] << '\n';

delete []arr;
```

Do not forget to free the allocated memory.

Pay attention to that in C++ there is the standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in the header `<algorithm>` that does the task. It returns iterator that points to the maximum element.

Comment: "and it should return the index of the maximum element" according to what? The user wants to return the maximum element, not the maximum element's index.

Comment: @John As I wrote the second argument can be for example equal to 0. In this case the function has undefined behavior. Simpler saying according to the qualification of the programmer.